# How to filter/clean a list in Python

Tags: python, list, null, filtering, data-cleaning

I have a list that has text and numbers as well as empty values. I'm looking to take:

```
products = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], ['productid="6836518"', 'productid="5965878"', 'productid="3851171"'], ['productid="6455623"'], [], ['productid="8024914"', 'productid="2871360"', 'productid="6694729"', 'productid="6760262"'], [], [], ['productid="6466698"', 'productid="5340641"', 'productid="6071996"', 'productid="5379225"'], ['productid="6683916"', 'productid="6690577"', 'productid="7117851"'], ['productid="7094467"'], ['productid="6628351"'], ['productid="5897930"'], ['productid="6812437"', 'productid="5379225"'], ['productid="7918467"', 'productid="7918466"'], []]
```

And return something like:

```
products2 =  [6836518, 5965878, 3851171, 6455623, 8024914, 2871360, 6694729, 6760262, 6466698, 5340641, 6071996, 5379225, 6683916, 6690577, 7117851, 7094467, 6628351, 5897930, 6812437, 5379225, 7918467, 7918466]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This single line solution should work using `re`:

```
import re
product = [int(re.search("\d+",e).group()) for l in products for e in l]
```

result of `product`:

```
[6836518,
 5965878,
 3851171,
 6455623,
 8024914,
 2871360,
 6694729,
 6760262,
 6466698,
 5340641,
 6071996,
 5379225,
 6683916,
 6690577,
 7117851,
 7094467,
 6628351,
 5897930,
 6812437,
 5379225,
 7918467,
 7918466]
```

Comment: This worked but only for those values that had "productid" in them. There are still returned values containing the syntax "data-thisProduct". . .

Answer (score 0):

So examine your data structure. You have a list of lists, where those inner lists contain zero or elements that look like `'productid="0123456"'` and you want to get those digits out.

You should be able to use `itertools.chain` for this:

```
products2 = []

for el in itertools.chain.from_iterable(products):
    if 'productid' in el:
        _, num = el.split('=')
        num = int(num.strip('"'))
        products2.append(num)
```

If you might have `productid='12345'` as well as `..."12345"` you can strip both types of quotes instead with `num = int(num.strip('"\''))` (note the escaped single quote, which I think looks cleaner than the equivalent `""""'"""`)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

data = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], ['productid="6836518"', 'productid="5965878"', 'productid="3851171"'], ['productid="6455623"'], [], ['productid="8024914"', 'productid="2871360"', 'productid="6694729"', 'productid="6760262"'], [], [], ['productid="6466698"', 'productid="5340641"', 'productid="6071996"', 'productid="5379225"'], ['productid="6683916"', 'productid="6690577"', 'productid="7117851"'], ['productid="7094467"'], ['productid="6628351"'], ['productid="5897930"'], ['productid="6812437"', 'productid="5379225"'], ['productid="7918467"', 'productid="7918466"'], []]
clean = []

for l in data:
    for item in l:
        clean.append(int(re.search('\d+', item).group(0)))

print(clean)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

With List Comprehension:

```
tmp = [ j for i in products for j in i]
result = [ int(i.split('=')[1].replace('"','')) for i in tmp]

print(result) # will give the desired output
```

Extending the list comprehension:

```
result= []

for i in products:
  if i:
    for j in i:
      tmp = j.split('=')
      result.append(int(tmp[1].replace('"','')))

print(result)
```